# Is speed a issue for using SQL Developer to do database copy?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, amazon-rds

We have several Oracle databases, each sized several gigs. Now we want to do a database copy, to a remote server. Inexperienced as I am, Sql Developer's database copy and Oracle's exp/imp functions seem to be most obvious options (cannot use data pump here).

We have heard that using sql developer will be slow. So anyone has the experience of how slow it would be? If we assume the connection speed is good.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Why don't you just try it and find out exactly how long it takes in your environment? No-one can do perf tests for you, and your "several gigs" is very vague.

Comment: Use exp/imp if you can't do datapump.

Comment: Why can't you use DataPump? If you have SQL access to the servers and can create a DBLink you can run `dbms_datapump` through SQL and copy e.g. a schema without any intermediate files.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name "Amazon RDS does not currently support using Data Pump to import data to a DB Instance in a VPC"

Comment: @Mat At this stage I'm asked to gather information. It's not my call to start the database copy.

Comment: @DavidAldridge  DB version is 11.1.0.6.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: You didn't mention RDS anywhere in your question. Then I'd say if you want to copy **all** tables exp/imp is fastest way. If you only want some tables, use a flat file export and `sqlldr` to import it.